# autocompletion in Jupyter with pyspark & scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

I am very envious of DataBricks autocompletion in it's jupyter notebooks, but I cannot get it to work on my local installation.

I dug up doc that %config IPCompleter.greedy=True
that works for python, but not with pyspark or spark-shell(scala).
Does anyone know how to make this work?

BTW: I am working with Spark 2.0.0 & Spark 2.11 on ubuntu 16.04 64bit.
Also, toree to work with Spark 2.0 & Spark2.11, I compiled 
toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT
That's in my binstar under hyoon.
https://anaconda.org/hyoon/toree

Comment: as far as I know none of these autocompletions work that good. I usually write and test my code in Intellij idea, and then move my code into the notebooks for presentations or plottings. I would like a better way but it may at best be what databricks has done, which was not that good either.

Comment: I use both Intellij n ensime, which is just about equal (at least with Emacs). I hope that jupyter could b integrated with ensime in the future and that should take care of scala side. spark-notebook and zeppline both seems a bit more experimental than jupyter. I had compile or implentation side.

Comment: I tested ensime+emacs ages ago. I found intellij is better overall and also way faster but still slow. I really liked it though. For someone who likes emacs (which I am), ensime+emacs is god send!

Comment: You know emacs stands for "Exclusive editor for Middle Aged Computer Science" Guys. ;)  Right? Yep, I can't put it down either even on my 3+ghz Haswell machine. Stuck with it since S+ and python days.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was solved as of Spark 2.2. Besure to set the environment variable correctly though. Now everything just works.

below is an important one!

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```